# Using dplyr to apply a function of several columns of an R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, map-function

*Using dplyr’s “verbs,” how can I apply a (general) function to a column of an R data frame, if that function depends on multiple columns of the data frame?*

Here’s a concrete example of the type of situation that I face. I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    d1 = c('2016-01-30 08:40:00 UTC', '2016-03-06 09:30:00 UTC'),
    d2 = c('2016-01-30 16:20:00 UTC', '2016-03-06 13:20:00 UTC'),
    tz = c('America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Chicago'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to convert the UTC times to local times, to get a data frame like this:

```
                   d1                  d2                  tz
1 2016-01-30 00:40:00 2016-01-30 08:20:00 America/Los_Angeles
2 2016-03-06 03:30:00 2016-03-06 07:20:00     America/Chicago
```

To do this, I would like to apply the following function, which converts UTC time to local time using the lubridate library, to the date columns:

```
getLocTime <- function(d, tz) {
    as.character(with_tz(ymd_hms(d), tz))
}
```

Using dplyr, it seems that the transformation

```
df %>% mutate(d1 = getLocTime(d1, tz), d2 = getLocTime(d2, tz))
```

should do the trick. However, it fails with the complaint `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): invalid 'tz' value`.

The only way I've managed to do the conversion to local time is with the rather ungainly assignment

```
df[c('d1', 'd2')] <- lapply(c('d1', 'd2'),
                            function(x) unlist(Map(getLocTime, df[[x]], df$tz)))
```

*Is there in fact a natural way to perform this transformation using dplyr idioms?*

Comment: This calls `getLocTime(c("2016-01-30 08:40:00 UTC", "2016-03-06 09:30:00 UTC"), c("America/Los_Angeles", "America/Chicago"))` for the 1st `mutate`, which does not work. You could vectorize your function, e.g. `vgetLocTime <- Vectorize(getLocTime, c("d", "tz"))`.

Comment: `Vectorize` your function, as @lukeA suggested, then you can also use `mutate_each` to make it easier to mutate multiple columns: `df %>% mutate_each(funs(getLocTime(., tz)), matches("d"))`

Comment: @lukeA: Perfect, that works! Thank you. (The dplyr documentation could be more explicit about the need to vectorize when applying column-mutating functions ... )

Comment: @eipi10: I did not know about `mutate_each` — thanks! The help page for `mutate_each` does not seem to mention `matches`. What is the precise form of the arguments of `matches`? Could there be multiple matches, i.e., would `matches("d1", "d2")` be an equivalent match?

Comment: `matches` is documented under `select`, which is the verb for selecting columns of a data frame. `matches` allows you to select columns using a regular expression. In this case, "d" will match any column whose name contains "d". Adjust as needed for your real column names, or you may prefer to use one of the other helper functions documented under `select` for selecting columns of a data frame.

Comment: @eipi10: (Pardon the last question!: it doesn't work. :/) But thanks for the explanation and for pointing me to the right documentation!

Comment: Yes, only a valid regular expression will work with `matches`. You could do `matches("d[12]")` (equivalent to, but shorter than `matches("d1|d2")`), but `"d"` alone will work unless you need to exclude other columns that contain "d" and other characters. For example, if you only wanted columns starting with "d" and ending with 1 through 5  you could do `matches("^d.*[1-5]$")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by lukeA, the problem occurs because `getLocTime` is not vectorized. So either you vectorize the function as proposed, or you perform your function rowwise:

```
 df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(d1 = getLocTime(d1, tz), d2 = getLocTime(d2, tz))
```

which makes sure that `getLocTime` is called with a single number and not a vector. I leave it up to you to determine which approach is faster.

Comment: I haven't checked timings, but, based on past experience, `rowwise` tends to be pretty slow.